# Robocopy /IF syntax doesn't match /XF syntax

Tags: robocopy

I've been trying to figure this out, and I am looking for someone to confirm for me that robocopy wildcards will NOT allow you to filter/include files (`/IF`) that CONTAIN a series of characters, but they will allow you to exclude files (`/XF`) that do.

As far as I understand you can use the `*` wildcard to filter files that START with a character or series of characters (`*a`, or `*april` would return `April_sales.xls`, but not `SalesSummary_April.pdf`), and you can use the same `*` wildcard to filter for file extension (`*.xls`).

I want something like `*apr*` to return files `April_sales.xls`, `SalesSummary_Apr.pdf`, and `Paprika.jpg`, but as far as I can tell, it's not possible.

However, that is exactly what the `/XF` syntax does, so it *seems* like it should be possible...

Can someone point me in a direction that will explain this or confirm this explicitly for me?

Edit: My actual robocopy script has nothing to do with 'apr' as you can see below - I'm trying to grab all pdfs that have 1016-N11 or 1016-C14 within the filename and exclude all other files in the directory that it comes across. Technically I don't even think I need to exclude (`/XF`) .jpg files but the *.pdf filter (`/IF`) doesn't even work.

`robocopy $remoteBasePath $homeBasePath /L`
`/IF *1016_N11* *1016-N11* *1016-C14* *1016_C14* *.pdf`
`/XD *Calculations* *archive*`
`/XF *.jpg`

Thanks for your help folks!

Comment: Your expectations about wildcards might be a bit off. See [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html). Your example "I want" would translate to `*apr*` = "Anyting (or nothing) plus literal string `apr` plus anything (or nothing)"  (`*`= "zero or more characters")

Comment: It would greatly help us all if you were to [Edit] your question to include a listing of test filenames/tree, the exact `Robocopy.exe` commandline you are using, the files it is selecting, and those which were expected. Also, as `Robocopy.exe` is not an internal command, (within `cmd.exe`), there doesn't seem to be a purpose for your [[tag:cmd]] .tag

Comment: @Stephan thanks for your reply! I think that's exactly what I need. I have added my actual code into the question now - I'm looking for any pdf files that that have the strings I bookended with the * wildcard. The files that I want will have an alphanumeric name followed by one of those wildcarded strings, followed by another set of numbers that can vary in length.

Comment: so `/IF *1016_N11*.pdf *1016-N11*.pdf *1016-C14*.pdf *1016_C14*.pdf` ? The "pdf filter" in your code does work, just not in the way you think. It includes *all* `*.pdf` files, making your previous "includes" worthless.